Find/replace with variables
I'm trying to write a perl script to remove strings from a mariadb database that contains articles from a Joomla website. Our AI tool is inserting extra junk in the database that needs to be removed. Here's an example of the type of string we need to remove:
<span class="wordai-block rewrite-block enable-highlight" data-id="53">

The difficulty is the data-id value may be some unknown number.
We also need to remove any closing </span> tags.
Here is the code I've developed so far, but I got stuck on the loop that's needed to search through the article once its identified to contain the above string.
use CGI;
use DBI;
use Date::Format      qw(time2str);
use Text::Wrap;
use strict;
use Encode;
use vars              qw($copy);
sub clean($$);
sub db_connect();
sub db_disconnect($);
sub write_sql($$);

my $dbh       = db_connect();
my $findtext = '<span class=\"wordai-block rewrite-block enable-highlight\" data-id=\"';
my $replace = '';
my $sql1      = "select id,alias,`fulltext` from db1_content where `fulltext` like \"%$findtext%\""; #"
my $sth0      = $dbh->prepare($sql1) or die "Cannot prepare: ". $dbh->errstr;
$sth0->execute() or die "cannot execute: ".$dbh->errstr();
print "sql1: $sql1\n";
my $dupe;
my $count=0;
while (my $ref1 = $sth0->fetchrow_hashref()) {
      $count++;
      print "$count Found instance: $ref1->{id} $ref1->{alias}\n";
      my $newstring = $ref1->{fulltext};
      $newstring =~ s/$findtext/$replace/g;
    
      print "$count: Updating: $ref1->{id}\n";
      my $sqlr        = "update db1_content set `fulltext` = ".$dbh->quote($newstring)." where id=$ref1->{id}";
}
print "\n";
db_disconnect($dbh);
exit 0;
sub write_sql($$) {
      my $dbh       = shift;
      my $sql       = shift;
      my $sth       = $dbh->prepare($sql);
      $sth->execute();
      $sth->finish();
      print "writing: $sql\n";
}
sub db_connect() {
      my %DB        = (
            'host'  => 'localhost',
            'db'    => 'dbtest',
            'user'  => 'joomla',
            'pass'  => 'pass',
      );
      return DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$DB{'db'};host=$DB{'host'}",
            $DB{'user'}, $DB{'pass'});
}
sub db_disconnect($) { my $dbh = shift; $dbh->disconnect(); }


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

I am not an expert in MariaDB, but there are several standard techniques for what you need:

Once you created an update statement (as you already have), dump it into a text file (or memory array if you expected number of update statements to be small enough). After the first loop reading data from DB is done and closed - start a second loop, now reading the prepared update statements and executing them one by one. As a variant, if you dump update statements into a file, you would be able to review it and execute through your favorite external ?sql tool.

Open two independent connections to DB - read from one, update through another in the same loop. No need to worry if these two connections will collide over data on the server side - that is a standard way of reading-modifying data for multi-user servers, and even if in this case both "users" are actually two connections from one application - that would still be fine.

Not sure if MariaDB can handle that, but many other RDBMS support cursor for update technique. So instead of using select to find records for correction, you can create a cursor, read data from it and then update the very same cursor. It will handle change to that particular record automatically.

Do all changes inside the DB without external scripts. That is a most common way to update records. But it can require a complicated SQL statement (or writing stored procedure).


Choose whatever approach looks easier to understand and implement.
